# How to manage users' access to items of other users in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, authorization, acl, zend-acl

I use a simple ACL inspired by [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unW0sjWdHCI). The `acl.global.php` has a structure like

```
return [
    'acl' => [
        'roles' => [
            'guest' => null,
            'member' => 'guest',
            'admin' => 'member'
        ],
        'resources' => [
            'allow' => [
                'Application\Controller\Index' => ['all' => 'member'],
                'Application\Controller\Error' => ['all' => 'member'],
                'Item\Controller\Process' => [
                    'index' => 'member',
                    'create' => 'member',
                    'showItem' => 'member', // website.tld/item/:id
                    'showList' => 'member' // website.tld/list-items
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'redirect_route' => [
            'params' => [],
            'options' => ['name' => 'error403']
        ]
    ]
];
```

There is an `Authorization\Acl\Acl` class, that extends `Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl` and adds to it functionality for the setup an object using the data from the config file above.

The third and last actor is the `Authorization\Module` class. There an ACL processing is added as `route` event listener and in this listener method `if (! $acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action))`, the user gets a `403` HTTP status code and the according view.

Now I want additionally to restrict the users' access to items (articles, orders, comments etc.). The user should only be able to see a detailed view of an `item` (`showItemAction`), if he is its owner/author. How to integrate such logic into the ACL?

Comment: You should read the documentation regarding ACL ['Assertions'](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.advanced.html#writing-conditional-acl-rules-with-assertions) as these offer you the ability to test if the role has access based on runtime criteria.

Comment: I've read it, but I don't understand, how to couple assertions with this "endpoint-driven" ACL logic.

Comment: @AlexP [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298894/how-to-build-an-acl-assertion-for-a-variable-value-in-zend-framework-2/37301924#37301924) works. But it's verbose and I'm not really happy with it.